# In Java, if one boolean true then all others become false

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was possible in Java to have a series of booleans such as:

```
    boolean boo1, boo2, boo3, boo4, boo5;
```

I want to make it so that if one of these booleans become true than all others become false. I know this can be done with a series of long if statements but is there a simpler way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: yes. how would they apply in this situation?

Comment: You could combine the `boolean`s into an array, and use for-loops to check/modify all booleans together.

Comment: You probably simply want a single `int` variable like `selectedIndex`. If `selectedIndex` is 2, then indices 0, 1, 3 and 4 are not selected. Set the variable to 1, and it automatically means that indices 0, 2, 3 and 4 are not selected.If you told us what you actually want to achieve, we could provide more help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html  and take a look at methods like `flip`. Additionally you can combine BitSets by standard logical operations.

Comment: Ok thanks! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: How long? 5? 500? 1000000?

Comment: [How to loop ArrayList](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-loop-arraylist-in-java/)

Comment: The real problem is this. Which booleans should become false? and which exact one should stay true? If **one** is true then all others are already false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array,

```
boolean bs = new boolean[10];
lightUp(bs, 6); // only bs[6] will be true after this
lightUp(bs, 0); // only bs[0] will be true after this
```

With the lightUp function defined as:

```
/**
 * modifies the passed-in array to make sure only
 * the selected index is set to true
 */
void lightUp(boolean[] bs, int index) {
   for (int i=0; i<bs.length; i++) bs[i] = false;
   bs[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: By default all the element of the `bs` array will be `false`, So I don't think loop is required to set them `false` again.

Comment: @YoungHobbit unless you're using the function more than once.